# Drop / Keep variables based on output in R

Tags: r

Suppose i have a data frame named mydata -

```
mydata <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), 
                      z=rnorm(10), k= rnorm(10))
```

There is a second data frame named data2 in which there is only one variable called var. The var contains the following content and it exists in 3 separate **rows**:

- x
- y
- k

I want to keep variables in mydata based on the observations of "var" from data2. In other words, i want to keep x,y and k in mydata as these variables exist in content (rows) of "var" in data2.

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Probably just `mydata[as.character(data2$var)]`

Comment: Thanks a ton for quick reply. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data2 = data.frame(var = c("x","y","k"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

mydata[data2$var]

         x            y          k    
1  -1.86010482 -0.009592772 -1.1306954
2   0.66826020 -1.262337011  1.3864280
3  -0.09408462  0.802072451 -0.1910587
4  -1.71244963  0.285884135 -0.3335212
5   0.90878484  1.061780225 -1.4161590
etc.
```

Comment: We don't know whether the 'var' is 'character' or 'factor'.  Anyway, it is safer to use DavidArenburg's comment